# Return only recipes that contains all ingredients Sql

Tags: sql, database, count, subquery, having-clause

I have these 3 tables:

Drinks

- drink_id
- name

Ingredients

- ingredient_id
- name

Opskrifter

- drink_id
- ingredient_id
- quantity

`Drinks` and `Ingredients` are cross-referenced in `opskrifter`.

I want to return all recipes from `opskrifter` that have ingredients from another table called

Stock

- name

So to make a gin and tonic, I need to have both gin and tonic in stock.

If I only have coke and tonic, I should return nothing

This is what I've got so far, copy/pasted from other post, but can't get any further.

```
Select
    d.*
From
    drinks d
Where
    not exists (select 1 
                from opskrifter r 
                where r.drink_id = d.drink_id 
                  and r.ingredient_id in (1, 2, 3))
```

Please help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to return all recipies from `opskrifter` that has ingredients from another table called `stock`.

I understand that you want drinks that have all ingredients that are listed in the `stock` table. Assuming that you have a column called `ingredient_id` in `stock`, you could phrase this as:

```
select o.drink_id
from opskrifter o
inner join stock s on s.ingredient_id = o.ingredient_id
group by o.drink_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from stock)
```

Alternatively, if you want drinks whose all ingredients are available in `stock`:

```
select o.drink_id
from opskrifter o
left join stock s on s.ingredient_id = o.ingredient_id
group by o.drink_id
having count(*) = count(s.ingredient_id)
```

Comment: i have a ingredient_id in stock, but this does not work. it returns both test recipies i have in opskrifter?

Comment: @JoachimAhmMortensen: it is not that clear what you are actually asking. I gave two queries, for two different purposes. If none of the two prodces the results that you want, then I would recommend providing sample data and desired results from all related tables. You could build a [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) for example.

Comment: sorry.. i had an error in my table.. This works perfectly. Thx alot :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation:

```
select o.drink_id
from opskrifter o
where r.ingredient_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by o.drink_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

You can use `join`, `in`, `exists` -- whatever -- to bring in the entire row from `drinks`.